# If statement == True regardless of user input in Python

Tags: python

I can't figure out why my code won't process the user input properly.

```
old = input("Type Yes or No.")

if old.upper() == "YES" or "Y":
    print("Success.")
```

When I type anything into the terminal, it still remains True for the old variable.

Ex. 
I type "sdafsdaf" into the terminal,
and it still prints "Success."

Any solutions? Thank you

Comment: Could it be that the conditional is failing the initial equal check, but coercing the string "Y" to a Boolean?

Answer (score 0):

```
if old.upper() == "YES" or  old.upper() == "Y":
```

Your condition was wrong. "Y" will always evaluate to true, since a string / char datatype has a truthy value.